# Why terraform generate the same timestamp by using `formatdate` function?

Tags: timestamp, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-step-functions, formatdatetime

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatdate.html
Th above is the doc of this function, I used this to append a timestamp on a name of the SageMaker batch transform job, which will be triggered from a stepfunction state machine:

```
locals {
  timestamp = formatdate("YYYYMMDDhhmmss", timestamp())
}
```

in stepfunction terraform file:

```
  definition = templatefile("stepfuntion.json",
    {
      xxx
      timestamp      = local.timestamp
)
```

in the "stepfuntion.json":

```
{...
          "TransformJobName": "jobname-${timestamp}",
  
          }
      },
        "End": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Specifically, the jobname is defined in  `"TransformJobName": "jobname-${timestamp}"`,
I applied terraform twice, 10am and 11am, but the second time it generated the same timestamp as the first time, am I missing something here? I thought this function will generate the real-time timestamp. I've been struggling for a whole morning now, many thanks.

Comment: Does the plan show a diff for the `definition` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works perfectly fine, I used your code as described in the question with the template file stepfuction.json

```
        # main.tf
        locals {
        current  = formatdate("YYYYMMDDhhmmss",timestamp())
    }
    output "tempasda"{
    value = templatefile("task.json", {timestamp = local.current, model_name="mymodel"})
    }
```

and the corresponding output

```
    $ terraform  apply -auto-approve |grep TransformJobName
            "TransformJobName": "jobname-20210106134614",

    $ terraform  apply -auto-approve |grep TransformJobName
            "TransformJobName": "jobname-20210106134615",

    $ terraform  apply -auto-approve |grep TransformJobName
            "TransformJobName": "jobname-20210106134617",
            
    $ terraform  apply -auto-approve |grep TransformJobName
            "TransformJobName": "jobname-20210106134618",
```

terrform version tested with **0.13.x and 0.14.x**

Comment: oh weired, I triggered again and it gave me the right time now, but why the second timestamp didn't change at all and that lead to a 'duplicated job name' error, so strange...

Comment: to be frank, before writing this,  I read the [formatdate](https://github.com/zclconf/go-cty/blob/e5225636c8c28add5fe543052061d90c63dada5e/cty/function/stdlib/datetime.go#L278) function code, It seems no problem to me. Then I posted my answer :)

Comment: Thanks @samtoddler , I found that it's not suitable to append a timestamp, because it'll only change the time after a terraform apply, so instead I think I will append a stepfunction execution id to the names, I tried different things but not working properly, I raised another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609804/how-to-append-stepfunction-execution-id-to-sagemaker-job-names, could you take a look please? Thanks a lot!