# How to append stepfunction execution id to SageMaker job names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I have a step function statemachine which creates SageMaker batch transform job, the definition is written in Terraform, I wanted to add the stepfunction execution id to the batch transform job names:

in stepfunction terraform file:

```
  definition = templatefile("stepfuntion.json",
    {
      xxxx
)
```

in the "stepfuntion.json":

```
{...
          "TransformJobName": "jobname-$$.Execution.Id",
  
          }
      },
        "End": true
      }
    }
  }
```

But after terraform apply, it didn't generate the actual id, it gave me `jobname-$$.Execution.Id`, can anyone help with this please?

Resources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html
"To access the context object, first specify the parameter name by appending .$ to the end, as you do when selecting state input with a path. Then, to access context object data instead of the input, prepend the path with $$.. This tells AWS Step Functions to use the path to select a node in the context object."

Can someone tell me what I'm missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var you are trying to use terraform doesn't know about it

> jobname-$$.Execution.Id.

That's something specific to the Step function and available within state machine not available for terraform.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Terraform then? Because the stepfunction is defined in Terraform.

Comment: I would recommend using [random_string](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/string) provider from terraform if you just want a random job name,

Comment: Will it give me different string everytime stepfunction gets triggered?

Comment: it gives a different string every time you apply/plan terraform.

Comment: by generating a random string, we don't really know the mapping relationship between the stepfunction execution & the jobs (although there's link available from the log directing to the related job)

Comment: The key thing here is that I don't want the name to be changed everytime I apply Terraform, instead, I want the name to be unique everytime the stepfunction gets triggered (so after one apply, the stepfunction might be triggered multiple times, and it will generate the same job name which will cause error because the job names need to be unique)

Comment: so you are already on the correct path, I am assuming inside the state machine you are using <jobname-$$.Execution.Id>, so terraform will leave it as it is but when the function runs in that case it will be different.

Comment: I tried, stepfunction also recognize it as a hard-coded name, it returned error `"cause": "1 validation error detected: Value 'jobname-$$.Execution.Id' at 'transformJobName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,62}`

Comment: it seems like working check [here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/f0331551c5d17836029d5a55485ceb28) or you want the evaluation of the var.

Comment: hmm am I misunderstanding anything? the example you shared with me, seems like it's showing the hard-coded `"ReservedTypeFallback-$$.Execution.Id":` instead of `"ReservedTypeFallback-real id"`

Comment: I don't want to append the id on the stepfunction job name, I wanted to append this name on the sagemaker batch transform job names (when stepfunction gets triggered, it will create a sagmaker batch transform job 'jobname', and I want to add the id on it 'jobname-execution-id')

Comment: so [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) are supported by step function. I tried to use one of them [here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/0b51e843b0fb815d8d3f230e25c42d84). Another way for you create a lambda for generating the random string and then use the output of that while constructing the job name

Comment: Thanks @samtoddler , I'll give it a proper read soon, my stepfunction json file is used to define a sagemaker job instead of a lambda, not sure if this is working but I'll give it a try. Cheers.

Comment: Hi I added this line `"executionId.$": "States.Format('somestring {}', $$.Execution.Id)"` to my batch transform job definition in stepfunction, but it shows me `could not be used to start the Task: [The field \"executionId\" is not supported by Step Functions]"`, any suguestions?

Comment: @Cecilia it depends where you are using that expression.

Comment: Thanks @samtoddler , I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721061/how-to-parse-stepfunction-executionid-to-sagemaker-batch-transform-job-name with a more detailed description of what I have tried by following what you sent me previously, could you take a look please?

Comment: @Cecilia and seems like there is a solution to your problem and that's exactly the similar way I shared my very first example with you [here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/0b51e843b0fb815d8d3f230e25c42d84)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading wawawa right, we are almost there.  Terraform creates the function, not an execution instance of it.  The Stepfunction assigns an execution ID only when it executes - and it changes every time!  So let Terraform create the code with a variable that Step Function will resolve at execution time.

So TransformJobName is getting the string literal "jobname--$$Execution.Id".  The right side looks fine, but the instruction the OP cited is trying to say we need to append a ".$" to your parameter name (on the left) to activate that substitution.  The instruction is written poorly but their examples are correct.

so your pair should look like this:

```json
"TransformJobName.$": "jobname-$$.Execution.Id",
```

I've found almost always my assignments say x.$ = $.y to reach into input or output,   or x.$ = $$.y if it's a context object.

Bonus tip: this is how I send arguments to Glue tasks.  Context is NOT part of the input path so you have to do something to include the context you want (execution.id in my case) as arguments.

```
    "Arguments": {
      "--inputbucket.$": "$.detail.bucket.name",
      "--inputobject.$": "$.detail.object.key",
      "--executionid.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
    }
```